# Can't get Action Bar in fragment class

Tags: android, class, android-actionbar, fragment

I have an activity with three fragment classes inside it. I get an error when trying to change the action bar title from inside of them. If I try to make the classes just public and not public static I get an error when I try to start that class. It should be pretty clear that the code is for preferences although that shouldn't change anything . Here's the code:

```
package com.simon.wikiics;

import android.preference.*;
import android.os.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MainSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.headers, target);
}

//If I don't make the classes static my app force closes when I try to start them
public static class NavigationSettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.navigation);
        //The getActionBar() is what is giving me the error
        getActionBar().setTitle("Navigation");

    }
}

public static class InterfaceSettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.interf);
        //The getActionBar() is what is giving me the error
        getActionBar().setTitle("Interface");
    }

}

public static class OtherSettingsActivity extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.other);
        //The getActionBar() is what is giving me the error
        getActionBar().setTitle("Other");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

A static class cannot see private fields of another class. You will need to use `getActivity().getActionBar()` to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks! Just another question, how do I start an activity via an intent from inside this fragment class?

Comment: @SweSnow context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyActivity.class));

Comment: I'm trying to turn off the action bar title using your approach (getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)) but I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: @SrikarReddy There are a ton of reasons this can happen. The most likely reason is that you are using an activity theme that does not include an action bar. I would double check that your theme is something like 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Answer (score 56):

@Robert Estivil
If you are using `AppCompatActivity` then use this:

```
actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated.  You can also 

    actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

Comment: Have you checked this out on an Android 2 phone to see if the cast really work?

Answer (score 15):

Though i am late in answering here.
I found arul's answer perfect, but now ActionbarActivity is deprecated so slight modification to that answer will finish the job:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 2):

With AppCompatActivity it is advised to shift to **Toolbar** instead of the action bar, But if you are not doing so then use this to get an instance of action bar.

```
((AppCompatActivity )getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use SherlokActionBar you can called your action bar using

```
ActionBar mActionBar = ((SherlockFragmentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```