# In Fragment Navigation Drawer. I am getting error in getActionBar.Can I know why and what is the error

Tags: android

/** Called when drawer is closed */

```
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) 
           {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
           }
```

/** Called when a drawer is opened */

```
          public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
         {
            getActionBar().setTitle("Select a river");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };
```

// Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout

```
           mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

// Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList

```
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), 
                R.layout.drawer_list_item  , 
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.rivers) 
            );
```

// Setting the adapter on mDrawerList

```
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

// Enabling Home button

```
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

// Enabling Up navigation

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output. what's the exact error ?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this from Fragment? Fragment does not have method `getActionBar();` [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013849/cant-get-action-bar-in-fragment-class)

Comment: IN Android Maninfest file if i change min sdk version 14 means I am getting output.But i use min sdk version 8 means i doesnot getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`.

Comment: If i use getSupportActionBar means i am getting error can I get full code GunaSeelan.

Comment: Are you using `appcompat` library?

Comment: May I know where you are calling this, in `MainActivity` or `NavigationDrawerFragment`?

Comment: Okay, If you use `getSupportActionBar` means what error you are getting?

Comment: error is: The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}

Answer (score 0):

Fragment does not have method *getActionBar()*.

A fragment is usually used as part of an activity's user interface and contributes its own layout to the activity. To provide a layout for a fragment, you must implement the *onCreateView()* callback method, which the Android system calls when it's time for the fragment to draw its layout.
So, fragment requires its activity in which it is present.

So, try *getActivity().getActionBar();*