# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

I'm new in android and testing my skills in different test applications. Now I'm trying to get data from Json url and create from Json's object favorite list. Gradle is finished without any problems, but every time when my app starts, it crashes with next error:

Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

I used as tutorial next resources:

for shared prefs: http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/

for Json parser: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

This is my code error and activity where is the error:

```
   06-17 17:05:14.124  10249-10249/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.boom.kayakapp, PID: 10249
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines
            at com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesListAdapter.getView(AirlinesListAdapter.java:102)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-17 17:05:14.153      932-932/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 932: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-17 17:05:16.543    1233-1266/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '26e93136 com.boom.kayakapp/com.boom.kayakapp.activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-17 17:05:38.432  10506-10506/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-17 17:05:38.432  10506-10506/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-17 17:05:39.009  10523-10523/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-17 17:05:39.009  10523-10523/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-17 17:05:51.855  10533-10533/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.boom.kayakapp, PID: 10533
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines
            at com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesListAdapter.getView(AirlinesListAdapter.java:102)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
            at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
            at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-17 17:05:51.887      932-932/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 932: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-17 17:06:51.514  11046-11046/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-17 17:06:51.514  11046-11046/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-17 17:06:52.206  11063-11063/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-17 17:06:52.207  11063-11063/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-17 17:07:03.184      932-932/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 932: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
06-17 17:07:06.919    1233-1266/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '3bd6cfb7 com.boom.kayakapp/com.boom.kayakapp.activities.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

AirlinesListAdapter:

```
    package com.boom.kayakapp.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.boom.kayakapp.R;
import com.boom.kayakapp.controllers.AppController;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines;
import com.boom.kayakapp.util.SharedPreference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AirlinesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Airlines> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<Airlines> favorites;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public AirlinesListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Airlines> favorites) {
        super(activity, R.layout.list_item, favorites);
        this.activity = activity;
        if(favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<>();
        else
            this.favorites = favorites;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView favoriteImg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return favorites.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Airlines getItem(int location) {
        return favorites.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView logoURL = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.logoURL);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        TextView site = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.site);
        TextView code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);

        holder.favoriteImg = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

        // getting airlines data for the row
        Airlines m = favorites.get(position);
        // thumbnail image
        logoURL.setImageUrl(m.getLogoURL(), imageLoader);
        // name
        name.setText(m.getName());
        // phone
        phone.setText("Phone: " + String.valueOf(m.getPhone()));
        // site
        site.setText("Web: " + String.valueOf(m.getSite()));
        // release code
        code.setText(String.valueOf(m.getCode()));

        /*If a product exists in shared preferences then set heart_red drawable
         * and set a tag*/
        if (checkFavoriteItem((Airlines) favorites)) {
            holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
            holder.favoriteImg.setTag("red");
        } else {
            holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
            holder.favoriteImg.setTag("grey");
        }

        return convertView;
    }
    /*Checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences*/
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Airlines checkAirlines) {
        boolean check = false;
//      List<Airlines> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity);
        if (favorites != null) {
            for (Airlines product : favorites) {
                if (product.equals(checkAirlines)) {
                    check = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return check;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Airlines airlines) {
        super.add(airlines);
        favorites.add(airlines);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Airlines airlines) {
        super.remove(airlines);
        favorites.remove(airlines);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

AirlineListFragment:

```
    package com.boom.kayakapp.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.boom.kayakapp.R;
import com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesListAdapter;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines;
import com.boom.kayakapp.util.SharedPreference;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AirlinesListFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "airlines_list";

    Activity activity;
    ListView airlinesListView;
    List<Airlines> airlines;
    AirlinesListAdapter airlinesListAdapter;

    public AirlinesListFragment() {
        airlines = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_airlines_list, container,
                false);
        findViewsById(view);

        airlinesListAdapter = new AirlinesListAdapter(activity, airlines);
        airlinesListView.setAdapter(airlinesListAdapter);
        airlinesListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        airlinesListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    private void findViewsById(View view) {
        airlinesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_airlines);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Airlines airlines = (Airlines) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(activity, airlines.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {
        ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);

        String tag = button.getTag().toString();
        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
            sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity, airlines.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(activity,
                    activity.getResources().getString(R.string.add_favr),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            button.setTag("red");
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
        } else {
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity, airlines.get(position));
            button.setTag("grey");
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
            Toast.makeText(activity,
                    activity.getResources().getString(R.string.remove_favr),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.boom.kayakapp.activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.boom.kayakapp.R;
import com.boom.kayakapp.adapters.AirlinesListAdapter;
import com.boom.kayakapp.controllers.AppController;
import com.boom.kayakapp.fragment.AirlinesListFragment;
import com.boom.kayakapp.fragment.FavoriteListFragment;
import com.boom.kayakapp.model.Airlines;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Fragment contentFragment;
    AirlinesListFragment airlinesListFragment;
    FavoriteListFragment favoriteListFragment;

    // JSON Node names
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    public static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String TAG_SITE = "site";
    public static final String TAG_LOGO = "logoURL";
    public static final String TAG_CODE = "code";

    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Airlines json url
    private static final String url = "https://www.kayak.com/h/mobileapis/directory/airlines";

    public ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public List<Airlines> airlinesList = new ArrayList<Airlines>();
    public ListView listView;
    public AirlinesListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new AirlinesListAdapter(this, airlinesList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // Listview on item click listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String phone = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone))
                        .getText().toString();
                String site = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.site))
                        .getText().toString();
                String logoURL = String.valueOf(((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.logoURL)));

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE, phone);
                in.putExtra(TAG_SITE, site);
                in.putExtra(TAG_LOGO, logoURL);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // changing action bar color
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest airlinesReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Airlines airlines = new Airlines();
                                airlines.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                airlines.setLogoURL(obj.getString("logoURL"));
                                airlines.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                airlines.setCode(obj.getInt("code"));
                                airlines.setSite(obj.getString("site"));

                                // adding airlines to movies array
                                airlinesList.add(airlines);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(airlinesReq);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /*
         * This is called when orientation is changed.
         */
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("content")) {
                String content = savedInstanceState.getString("content");
                if (content.equals(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
                    if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                        setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                        contentFragment = fragmentManager
                                .findFragmentByTag(FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(AirlinesListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                airlinesListFragment = (AirlinesListFragment) fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(AirlinesListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                contentFragment = airlinesListFragment;
            }
        } else {
            airlinesListFragment = new AirlinesListFragment();
//          setFragmentTitle(R.string.app_name);
            switchContent(airlinesListFragment, AirlinesListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (contentFragment instanceof FavoriteListFragment) {
            outState.putString("content", FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        } else {
            outState.putString("content", AirlinesListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


//  @Override
//  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//      return true;
//  }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_favorites:
                setFragmentTitle(R.string.favorites);
                favoriteListFragment = new FavoriteListFragment();
                switchContent(favoriteListFragment, FavoriteListFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);

                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate());

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
            //Only FavoriteListFragment is added to the back stack.
            if (!(fragment instanceof AirlinesListFragment)) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            contentFragment = fragment;
        }
    }

    protected void setFragmentTitle(int resourseId) {
        setTitle(resourseId);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(resourseId);

    }

    /*
     * We call super.onBackPressed(); when the stack entry count is > 0. if it
     * is instanceof ProductListFragment or if the stack entry count is == 0, then
     * we finish the activity.
     * In other words, from ProductListFragment on back press it quits the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else if (contentFragment instanceof AirlinesListFragment
                || fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
package com.boom.kayakapp.model;

public class Airlines {
    private String name, logoURL, phone, site;
    private int code;

    public Airlines() {
    }

    public Airlines
            (String name, String logoURL, int code, String phone, String site) {
        this.name = name;
        this.logoURL = logoURL;
        this.code = code;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.site = site;

    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getLogoURL() {return logoURL;}
    public void setLogoURL(String logoURL) {this.logoURL = logoURL;}

    public int getCode() {return code;}
    public void setCode(Integer code) {this.code = code;}

    public String getPhone() {return phone;}
    public void setPhone(String phone) {this.phone = phone;}

    public String getSite() {return site;}
    public void setSite(String site) {this.site = site;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setAdapter calls getCount but the list is null so just init the airlines list like this

```
    public AirlinesListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Airlines> favorites) {
    super(activity, R.layout.list_item, favorites);
    this.activity = activity;
    if(favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<>();
   else 
        this.favorites = favorites;
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

}
```

second solution : 
init the array in the fragment

```
 public AirlinesListFragment() {
    airlines = new ArrayList<>();

  }
```

this should solve your problem

check out this page for the solution : [Can't get Action Bar in fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013849/cant-get-action-bar-in-fragment-class)

Comment: The second way helped me thank you a lot! But unfortunately it's showed another error, but I moved on ahead, thanks for help!!!

Comment: ok update your question with the new error and ill try to help you

Comment: Itzik Samara, thank you for help but I just comment **getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);** in **AirlinesListFragment** because it was duplicate of first string **getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);** and then app showed me next error (it sounds like curse)

error I updated together with new model activity

Comment: your problem is here checkFavoriteItem((Airlines) favorites) favorites are List<Airlines> and you case it to just Airlines